# How to dynamically set LocationStrategy class

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

How to dynamically configure AppModuleNgFactory in Angular 2 application compiled with ahead of time compiler?

`LocationStrategy` provider class should be set depending on `window.isCordova` environment variable

```
{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: window.isCordova ? HashLocationStrategy : PathLocationStrategy
}
```

If the application is not compiled with AOT, it works without any issue. But when its compiled with AOT, `LocationStrategy` provider is always set to `HashLocationStrategy`.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useFactory: locationStrategyFactory, deps: [PlatformLocation] },
```

The locationStrategyFactory function should look like:

```
const locationStrategyFactory = (_platformLocation: PlatformLocation) => {
  return (isUseHash ?  new HashLocationStrategy(_platformLocation) : new PathLocationStrategy(_platformLocation) );
};
```